# Two ways of entering a directory by inode number?

Tags: find, inode

If I want to enter a directory by its inode number, why

```
cd $(find . -inum $inode_num)
```

works, but the following command does not work:

```
find . -inum $inode_num -exec cd {} \;
```

what's the difference between these two, and why is the 2nd one wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` is not a program that can be `exec`uted, it's a built-in shell command. It has to be, since it's too hard to *change current directory in parent process*.